# How to select the first letter of each word from a table cell in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string-parsing

How can I select the first letter of each word in MySQL using a query?

So this table

```
+----+----------------------------+
| id | str                        |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | Hello my name is MCEmperor |
|  2 | How are you doing?         |
+----+----------------------------+
```

would return

```
+----+----------------------------+
| id | str                        |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | HmniM                      |
|  2 | Hayd                       |
+----+----------------------------+
```

I guess it's something with `SUBSTRING` and `LOCATE` and maybe I need a loop (to find all spaces or something)...

Is it possible within a query? How should I do that?

Comment: seems impossible by routine query what about writing special function for this?

Comment: You'd be far better off doing this client-side. String manipulation of this sort is not what sql is designed for, unless you want to write a stored procedure/UDF for it.

Comment: And what about using a function? Can it within a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could simply split by space? Use this stored proc : http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,78776,148332#msg-148332

You can then retrieve the first letters of each word and use GROUP_CONCAT in a GROUP BY Id to put the letters back into one line per initial text.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a `WHERE` clause that matches only part of the data in the cell.  You can do that like so:

```
SELECT str 
from (table name) 
WHERE str LIKE 'H%'
```