# Extract first character of each word in MySQL using a RegEx

Tags: mysql, regex

In my MySQL database I have a column of strings in UTF-8 format for which I want to extract the first character using a RegEx, for example.

Assuming a RegEx which ONLY extracts the following characters:

```
ਹਮਜਰਣਚਕਨਖਲਨ
```

And given the following string:

```
ਹੁਕਮਿ ਰਜਾਈ ਚਲਣਾ ਨਾਨਕ ਲਿਖਿਆ ਨਾਲਿ ॥੧॥
```

The only characters extracted would be:

```
ਹਰਚਨਲਨ
```

I know the following steps would be required to solve this problem:

- Break the string into individual words (substrings) by using space as the delimiter
- For each word extract the first letter (substring of a substring) if it matches what is in the regex of valid characters

I have looked at all the similar questions/answers on SO and none have been able to solve my problem thus far.

Comment: Did you look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8313154/2812842

Comment: Yes, but its not a very helpful answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved this with the help of a programmer friend of mine. I directly pasted the following piece of code into the `SQL` section of my database in `PhpMyAdmin`:

```
delimiter $$
drop function if exists `initials`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `initials`(str text, expr text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
begin
    declare result text default '';
    declare buffer text default '';
    declare i int default 1;
    if(str is null) then
        return null;
    end if;
    set buffer = trim(str);
    while i <= length(buffer) do
        if substr(buffer, i, 1) regexp expr then
            set result = concat( result, substr( buffer, i, 1 ));
            set i = i + 1;
            while i <= length( buffer ) and substr(buffer, i, 1) regexp expr do
                set i = i + 1;
            end while;
            while i <= length( buffer ) and substr(buffer, i, 1) not regexp expr do
                set i = i + 1;
            end while;
        else
            set i = i + 1;
        end if;
    end while;
    return result;
end$$

drop function if exists `acronym`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `acronym`(str text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
begin
    declare result text default '';
    set result = initials( str, '[ੴਓੳਅੲਸਹਕਖਗਘਙਚਛਜਝਞਟਠਡਢਣਤਥਦਧਨਪਫਬਭਮਯਰਲਵੜਸ਼ਖ਼ਗ਼ਜ਼ਫ਼ਲ਼]' );
    return result;
end$$
delimiter ;

UPDATE scriptures SET search = acronym(scripture)
```

Just to explain the last line:

- `scriptures` is the table I want to update
- `search` is a new empty column I created inside the table to store the result
- `scripture` is an existing column inside the `scriptures` table with all the strings I want to extract from
- `acronym` is the function previously declared which is looking to match the first letter of each word with a character from the RegEx `[ੴਓੳਅੲਸਹਕਖਗਘਙਚਛਜਝਞਟਠਡਢਣਤਥਦਧਨਪਫਬਭਮਯਰਲਵੜਸ਼ਖ਼ਗ਼ਜ਼ਫ਼ਲ਼]`

So this final line of the code will go through each row of the column `scripture`, apply the function `acronym` to it and store the result in the new `search` column.

Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I realy don't know MySql Regex Syntax and restrictions(never used), but you can add leading space before string, and match with something simple like this: " ([ਮਜਰਣਚਕਨਖਲਨ]{1})"

So, if you concatenate matched groups you will have this string "ਰਚਨਲਨ"(only "ਹ" not matched, because it's not exists in sample")

in C# it may look like this(working sample):

```
namespace TestRegex
{
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // leading space(to match first word too)
            // + sample string
            var sample = " ";
            sample +=  "ਹੁਕਮਿ ਰਜਾਈ ਚਲਣਾ ਨਾਨਕ ਲਿਖਿਆ ਨਾਲਿ ॥੧॥"; 

            // Regex pattern that will math space, and
            // if next character in set - add it to "match group 1"
            var pattern = " ([ਮਜਰਣਚਕਨਖਲਨ]{1})";

            // select every "match group 1" from matches as array
            var result = from Match m in Regex.Matches(sample, pattern) 
                         select m.Groups[1];

            // concatenate array content into one string and
            // show it in message box to user, for example..
            MessageBox.Show(string.Concat(result)); 
        }
    }
}
```

in most non-query languages it will be look almost same. For example in php you need to do preg_match_all, and in foreach loop add "$match[i][1]"(every "match group 1") from every match to end of one single string.

well.. pretty simple. but not for mysql...

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code that will do this?

Comment: Yes(added to answer), but in C# only.

Comment: Thanks so much for the C# version. I was also thinking to do this in PHP but I really wanted a pure SQL solution